# Maven best practice for generating multiple jars with different/filtered classes?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I developed a Java utility library (similarly to Apache Commons) that I use in various projects. 
In addition to fat clients, I also use it for mobile clients (PDA with J9 Foundation profile). 
In time the library that started as a single project spread over multiple packages. As a result I end up with a lot of functionality, which is not really needed in all the projects.

Since this library is also used inside some mobile/PDA projects I need a way to collect just the used classes and generate the actual specialized jars.

Currently in the projects that are using this library, I have Ant jar tasks that generate (from the utility project) the specialized jar files (ex: my-util-1.0-pda.jar, my-util-1.0-rcp.jar) using include/exclude jar task features. This is mostly needed due to the size constraints on the generated jar file, for the mobile projects.

Migrating now to Maven I just wonder if there are any best practices to arrive to something similar. I consider the following scenarios:

**[1]** - additionally to the main jar artifact (**my-lib-1.0.jar**) also generating inside **my-lib** project the separate/specialized artifacts using classifiers (ex: **my-lib-1.0-pda.jar**) using Maven Jar Plugin or Maven Assembly Plugin filtering/includes. I'm not very comfortable with this approach since it pollutes the library with library consumers demands (filters).

**[2]** - Create additional Maven projects for all the specialized clients/projects, that will "wrap" the "my-lib" and generate the filtered jar artifacts (ex: **my-lib-wrapper-pda-1.0** ...etc). As a result, these wrapper projects will include the filtering (to generate the filtered artifact) and will depend just on the "my-lib" project and the client projects will depend on **my-lib-wrapper-xxx-1.0** instead of **my-lib-1.0**. This approach may look problematic since even that will let "my-lib" project intact (with no additional classifiers and artifacts), basically will double the number of projects since for every client project I'll have one lib, just to collect the needed classes from the "my-util" library ("my-pda-app" project will need a "my-lib-wrapper-for-my-pda-app" project/dependency).

**[3]** - In every client project that uses the library (ex: **my-pda-app**) add some specialized Maven plugins to trim out (when generating the final artifact/package) the classes that are not required (ex: maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, proguard-maven-plugin).

What is the best practice for solving this kind of problems in the "Maven way"?

Answer (score 24):

The Maven general rule is "one primary artifact per POM" for the sake of modularity and the reasons one shouldn't break this convention (in general) are very well explained in the [How to Create Two JARs from One Project (...and why you shouldn’t)](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/) blog post. There are however justified exceptions (for example an EJB project producing an EJB JAR and a client EJB JAR with only interfaces). Having said that:

The mentioned [blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/) (also check [Using Maven When You Can't Use the Conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html)) explains how you could implement **Option 1** using separate profiles or the **JAR plugin**. If you decide to implement this solution, keep in mind that this should be an exception and that it might make dependency management trickier (and, as you mentioned, pollute the project with "client filtering logic"). Just in case, I would use several JAR plugin executions here.

**Option 2** isn't very different from **Option 1** IMO (except that it separate things): basically, having N other wrapping/filtering projects is very similar with having N filtering rules in one project. And if filtering makes sense, I prefer Option 1.

I don't like **Option 3** at all because I think it shouldn't be the responsibility of a client of a library to "trim out" unwanted things. First, a client project doesn't necessarily have the required knowledge (what to trim) and, second, this might create a big mess with other plugins.

**BUT** if the fat clients are **not** using the whole **my-lib** (like server-side code would require the whole EJB JAR), then filtering isn't the right "maven way" to handle your situation. The right way would be **Option 4**: put everything common in a project (producing **my-lib-core-1.0.jar**) and specific parts in specific projects (that will produce **my-lib-pda-1.0.jar** etc). Clients would then depend on the core artifact and specialized ones.

Comment: The main concern here is the PDA/mobile client (constrained size/memory) and not the fat client or the server were the actual lib/jar size is not problematic (for instance you may use a single class from apache-commons-xxx, but still get the full jar for it). What I' looking for is a Maven best practice to remove/filter from a bigger project just the needed classes into a specific application.
This look more like an obfuscator task that also support pruning but still don't know how this might fit in Maven landscape.

I'll still prefer putting it to the client/consumer side/project (option 3)

Comment: @jaguard I understand the constraint and the maven best practice would be option 4 (not sure to understand why this would be a problem). If you really don't want to implement it, then I think option 1 is the best second choice. Option 3 will IMO lead to many problems (as I wrote).