# Conditionally build EAR file with maven

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I have some trouble finding a solution to build different versions of my EAR (with the maven-ear-plugin).

What I would want is to be able to either produce an EAR for production or an EAR for tests, where the test EAR has different ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptors as well as some additional classes from the src/test folders.

The only way I've found so far, is to introduce a profile "blubb" where I override the jar-plugin configuration to include the ejb-jar.xml from src/test/resources as well as some java files, and add a custom suffix to my artifact id (or set a classifier). Then introduce the same profile in my deployment pom, where I depend on the artifacts possessing the suffix, to build a modified EAR.

I've read at various sources, that it is EVIL (i.e. not the Maven way) to produce different jars of the same project depending on profiles.
(e.g. at 
[Maven best practice for generating multiple jars with different/filtered classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424015/maven-best-practice-for-generating-multiple-jars-with-different-filtered-classes)
or
http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/)

So my question is, how can I do this instead? If I build an additional module with my test specific code to include in my deployment conditionally on a profile, I have the problem that my ejb-jar.xml needs to reside in the META-INF directory of exactly that jar file, since my additional "test" module will be contained in a different jar, the ejb-jar.xml will therefore not be applied to the ejbs in my original jar.

Any suggestions, how I could solve this problem (producing a special test ear with modified deployment descriptors and additional classes) the maven way?

Tipps and insights are highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some way to achieve, what I wanted, using the maven-dependency-plugin.

The basic problem was, that no code should have been duplicated, and yet, the same module should be built with additional/replaced content on demand.

The way I did it, was to make a second module, and within declare the module I wanted to modify as sole dependency. Then in the build cycle I added the maven-dependency-plugin with goal "unpack-dependencies" and selected to unpack the original dependency into the target/classes folder at "prepare-package" time.

That way I got a second module, which had the content of the first module, plus some modifications I could then make to the main sources of my adjusted module.

Altogether this is still everything but pretty, in my opinion Maven had its time, but now it's time for a better build tool ;-)

By the way, if anybody knows a more elegant solution, I'm still open... My problem often was, that under no circumstances I wanted to duplicate my configuration or even my code. And it seems that Maven makes this really hard...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is *not* to create separated EAR's for test/prod etc from the same . but if you really like to do that you should create two separate ear modules:

```
 +-- root (pom.xml)
      +--- mod-ejb (pom.xml)
      +--- mod-xxx (pom.xml) 
      +--- mod-ear (pom.xml)
      +--- mot-it-ear (pom.xml)
```

This means having two EAR modules which can have different descriptors etc.

Comment: But let's say I have 200 modules, each of which gets installed in my local repo, then I execute my deployment pom, where I collect all the 200 dependencies and pack them into my ear. I'm not sure, how I should adjust the content of the single projects in that step, if 50 of the 200 projects need an ejb-jar.xml in their META-INF for example. I would have had to build them differently in the first place, with a different artifact id, wouldn't I? So all the 200 projects would have had to be differently, and I don't know how to achieve that, can't really duplicate each module...

Comment: The reason for two ears is, that certain components need to be mocked out for a certain type of test against the ear...